# I get a weird error from the following awk command in linux

Tags: linux, bash

```
`awk '{print "ssh -q " $1 " \"echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr\";"}' essentials`
```

It is supposed to connect to bunch of hostnames from the file "essentials" and echo their disk space usage. If I get rid of the back ticks you can see what is being executed:

```
ssh -q hostname1 "echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr";
ssh -q hostname2 "echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr";
ssh -q hostname3 "echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr";
```

Actual output:

```
-bash-3.2$ `awk '{print "ssh -q " $1 " \"echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr\";"}' essentials`
bash: echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr: No such file or directory

hostname2
/dev/xvda3             23G   13G  9.2G  59% /usr

hostname3
/dev/xvda3             23G  1.5G   21G   7% /usr
```

Any ideas why that first command doesn't work?

Comment: What's the `essentials` contents?

Comment: Essentials contains host names...1 per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr` is treated as a single command, use this instead:

```
`awk '{print "ssh -q " $1 " bash -c \"echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr\";"}' essentials`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xargs --arg-file essentials -I {} ssh -q \{\} bash -c "echo && hostname && df -h | grep /usr"
```